# cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character' while using hash package in R

Tags: python, r, dictionary, hash

I am trying to convert a piece of python code to R. In python, a dictionary within a dictionary is used. So I am trying to utilise the hash package in R,

Python code:

```
titles = {
'NAME' :{
    'exact':['NAME']
    ,'partial':[]
    }
, 'Dt' :{
    'exact':['Dt']
    ,'partial':[]
    }
, 'CC' :{
    'exact':[]
    ,'partial':[]
    }
      }
```

And the R code is,

```
library(hash)
titles = hash(("NAME" = list("exact"=list('NAME'),"partial"=list())),
          ("Dt" = list("exact"=list('Dt'),"partial"=list())),
          ("CC" = list("exact"=list(),"partial"=list())))
```

But when i try use this code with hash environment, I am getting this below error.

```
Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

When I try to replace hash with list, its working fine. But, I am using key/value pair(hash package) mainly because I have to play around with inner dictionary, I mean change the inner dictionary values based on the outer dictionary keys. Any idea why I am getting this error or any alternative approach.

Updating below to make the question still more clear.

To explain it further, I am creating it as key/value pairs(hash package) mainly because I am going to use the below logic on the dictionaries which heavily use key/value pairs. I am not sure if this can be easily done in R list without key/value pairs.

```
another_dict = {}
multiples_dict = {}
adj_title = 'Dt'
for outer_key,outer_value in titles.iteritems():
        for exact in outer_value['exact']:
            if exact == adj_title:
               another_dict[actual_title] = outer_key
               multiples_dict[outer_key] = multiples
        for partial in inner_dict['partial']:
            if partial in adj_title:
               another_dict[actual_title] = outer_key
               multiples_dict[outer_key] = multiples
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to achieve by saying "change inner dict values based on outer dict keys"? Can you provide a small illustrative example?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated the question with what I am going to do with the key/value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get rid of the parens surrounding each of the key/value pairs as in:

```
library(hash)
titles = hash("NAME" = list("exact"=list('NAME'),"partial"=list()),
          "Dt" = list("exact"=list('Dt'),"partial"=list()),
          "CC" = list("exact"=list(),"partial"=list()))
```

When you include the parens `hash(  (a=b) )`, the object `(a=b)` is being passed as an expression and not a key/value pair

Comment: Oh my bad. I somehow missed it. Thanks for that.